# Split columns in to rows in google spread sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unpivot

I have following table:

```
ID    Event    Event2     Event3
102   181      182        184
103   5        7          8
```

I want to convert in into:

```
ID    Event
102   181   
102   182 
102   184
103   5
103   7
103   8
```

I tried with pivot table but no success. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A2&"|"&"|"&$B$2:$D$2);"|");
               SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A3&"|"&"|"&$B$3:$D$3);"|")})
```

[image]

---

**custom formula builder: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xjrgn0neqdEIkE1OHJepdKtqGYbBeFqK06CpXEUmVsg/edit#gid=497657342)**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this if there are hundreds of rows?

Comment: @JanakaDombawela you can try: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xjrgn0neqdEIkE1OHJepdKtqGYbBeFqK06CpXEUmVsg/edit#gid=497657342