# Analyse multiple columns per row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I need to combine the data of three different columns. Thus, I have this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| ID | ID Data | Markdown 1 | Markdown 2 | Markdown 3 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   G     |     X2     |    X3      |    X4      | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |   B     |     X6     |    X7      |    X8      | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 5  |   Z     |     X3     |    X4      |    X5      | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| etc ... 100 rows
```

In the end, I want one column saying "Markdowns", thus that combines the different columns. However, I want to keep the row data, meaning I need to see for which ID's which markdowns were put:

```
----------------------------
| ID | ID Data | Markdowns | 
----------------------------
| 1  | G       |    X2     | 
----------------------------
| 1  | G       |    X3     | 
----------------------------
| 1  | G       |    X4     | 
----------------------------
| 2  | B       |    X6     |   
----------------------------
| 2  | B       |    X7     | 
----------------------------
| 2  | B       |    X8     | 
----------------------------
| 5  | Z       |    X3     | 
----------------------------
| 5  | Z       |    X4     | 
----------------------------
| 5  | Z       |    X5     | 
----------------------------
| etc ...
```

I need this to create pivot's and graphs to show how many and which markdowns for which ID were put. Now I need to create three different pivots and combine the data manually.

I already checked [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119793/split-columns-in-to-rows-in-google-spread-sheets) formula but with that one, it seems I have to add the formula for each row manually.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi Vioncent, did you see the [duplicate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115804/45867)?  Especially the answer with the link to  [Formula to array all columns with first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060844/formula-to-array-all-columns-with-first-column)

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 "♠"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&C1:C&"♠"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&D1:D&"♠"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&E1:E, )
 ,,999^99), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!!!!